# AEM Personalisation without Target integration

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to personalise the banner content of my site homepage depending on the other site sections (segments) a visitor has previously and/or most commonly visited.

My site is basically split into 3 sections SectionA/SectionB/SectionC. Assuming a visitor frequents the SectionA most often, one would assume I could class them into sectionA segment. Likewise for the other site sections. Each of my site sections is Tagged with the name of that section.

The idea is that next time the visitor visits the my homepage, the content displayed would then be personalised to match the segment they are assumed to belong too.

I have plenty of experience personalising content with Adobe Target, but next to zero without. Am I right in thinking this can be achieved via clientContext or contextHub?

PS: I have managed to get this working with contextHub tagCloud with segments based on tagCount>n, however this uses session storage by default and I can't find a way to configure persistent storage short of writing code to override the OOTB tagcloud store. Ideally, I'd like to write a persistent cookie and have my segment resolve based on the cookie value.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this Adobe Helpx article :- **https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/personal.html**

You can find good answers by expert on AEM at Adobe AEM forum:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html

I hope this will help you.

Thanks and Regards
Kautuk Sahni